# unit-tests SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I get this error:

```
D:\nginx\ibdrweb\webapps\ibdr-document-2\doc-app\sources\forms\dynamic-form\lus\lus.js:1
import { Tools } from "@ShareUtils/tools";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

when i try to execute the following comand:

```
ts-mocha -p doc-app/tests/tsconfig.json doc-app/tests/lus-tests.ts
```

This issue was discussed here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26018 and was closed.
Attempt to change **"module": "commonjs"** at tsconfig.json doesn't help.
A lot of people wrote that **the issue still actual**.

My project looks like this

```
|- doc-app
|    |- < many direcotiries used at tests.ts >
|    |- tests
|          lus-tests.ts
|          tsconfig.json
|
|- node_modules
|- tsconfig.json
```

Note: node "v10.16.0"

tsconfig.json *at tests direcory*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
 },
 "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
   "useWebpackText": true,
    "useTranspileModule": true,
    "doTypeCheck": true,
    "forkChecker": true
 },
 "include": [
   "./"
 ],
 "exclude": [
   "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

useful part of package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/chai": "4.1.7",
  "@types/mocha": "5.2.7",
  "@types/sinon": "7.0.13",
  ...
  "chai": "4.2.0",
  ...
  "mocha": "6.1.4",
  ...
  "sinon": "7.3.2",
  ...
  "ts-mocha": "6.0.0",
  "ts-node": "8.4.1",
  "typescript": "2.9.2", //if change it to "3.6.3" it dosen't help
}
```

If i specify "module": "exnext" at the tsconfig.json, then error is

```
D:\nginx\ibdrweb\webapps\ibdr-document-2\doc-app\tests\lus-tests.ts:1
import "mocha";
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
```

***Note:*** import { Tools } from "@ShareUtils/tools"; Module "tools" in node_modules

Comment: If the test does not import the module (which in turn depends on other modules from node_modules), then it runs without errors. As soon as a dependency appears that goes to node_modules, an "Unexpected token" error is generated.

The question is how to run a unit test written in typescript correctly, in which there are dependencies from node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is caused because your JavaScript is not being compiled by TypeScript. You will need to able `allowJs` for that file to work as expected. The second error makes sense, node.js wouldn’t understand your ES modules code when you’re changing the module output away from CommonJS.

Comment: By a second error, I understand why this is so. My tconconfig.son there is the option "module": "commonjs". The mistake was posted as an example only with "module": "exnext" option. By a first error: the compilation error occurs as soon as a dependency is detected the node_modules. In the module under test, there are many dependencies that refer to node_modules